# how to show any one radio button in checked state with same different input name?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using 3 radio button with 3 different input names. I am using this method, because I want to get the value of unchecked button too.
But in this case, 3 radio buttons are getting checked simultaneously. I need to overcome this. I want only one radio button to be in checked state.

```js
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
foreach($_POST['job_seeker'] as $company=>$row){
    foreach($row as $job_seeker){
        echo $job_seeker;
    }
}

foreach($_POST['employer'] as $company=>$row){
    foreach($row as $employer){
        echo $employer;
    }
}

foreach($_POST['consultant'] as $company=>$row){
    foreach($row as $consultant){
        echo $consultant;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="chk" action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden"  name="job_seeker[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio"  id="job_seeker1"  name="job_seeker[0][e]" value="active"  />
 <label for="job_seeker1">Job Seeker</label>

 <input type="hidden"  name="employer[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio"  id="employer1" name="employer[0][e]" value="active"  />
 <label for="employer1">Employer</label>

 <input type="hidden"  name="consultant[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio" id="consultant1" name="consultant[0][e]" value="active"  />
 <label for="consultant1">Consultant</label>

    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok" />
 </form>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good use-case for a `radio`, try instead using a `checkbox` which is designed for exactly this - allowing a boolean value. Quick example here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox

Comment: **1** You should use all radio input with same name if you want to check only one radio at a time... **2** you can't get the unchecked radio buttons value after submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute has to be the same for every radio in order for them to work properly. You can use the `value` to distinguish between the radios. Here's a simplified example:

```
<input type="radio" name="role" value="job_seeker" />
<input type="radio" name="role" value="employer" />
<input type="radio" name="role" value="consultant" />
```

And in PHP something like this:

```
$job_seeker = "inactive";
$employer = "inactive";
$consultant = "inactive";

if (isset($_POST["role"])) {
    if ($_POST["role"] == "job_seeker") {
        $job_seeker = "active";
    } elseif ($_POST["role"] == "employer") {
        $employer = "active";
    } else {
        $consultant = "active";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use radio buttons the way they should be used, you should give them the same name. Then only one item can be selected

Comment: Thanks @Nico Haase.   Ok I will use same name.But I want to get the unchecked value also.If the radio button is checked,I want to get it as active.If the radio button unchecked means,I want to get it as inactive.how to get the individual value using foreach??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Use the same name attribute and compare them at php level as below. Also, change the value attribute to differentiate.

```html
<form name="chk" action="" method="post">


 <input type="hidden"  name="job_seeker[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio"  id="job_seeker1"  name="job_seeker[0]" value="1"  />
 <label for="job_seeker1">Job Seeker</label>



 <input type="hidden"  name="employer[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio"  id="employer1" name="job_seeker[1]" value="2"  />
 <label for="employer1">Employer</label>



 <input type="hidden"  name="consultant[0][e]" value="inactive"  />
 <input type="radio" id="consultant1" name="job_seeker[2]" value="3"  />
 <label for="consultant1">Consultant</label>


<input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok" />
</form>


<?php 

$answer = $_POST['job_seeker'];  
if ($answer == "1") {          
    $jobseeker='active'; 
 $employer='inactive';
 $consultant='inactive';
}else if($answer == "2") {          
    $jobseeker='inactive'; 
 $employer='active';
 $consultant='inactive';
}else if($answer == "3") {          
    $jobseeker='inactive'; 
 $employer='inactive';
 $consultant='active';
}
?>
```